# Divide the number in regular interval

Tags: math, statistics

The requirement is to divide the min & max number range to some intervals

For eg : Min = 0 ,Max =100, Intervals count =6 output = [0,20,40,60,80,100]

The algo should work for multiple number combination like negative to positive, negative  to negative etc . My solution is failing for one of these number combination. Any hints ?

Comment: The increment is just `(max-min)/(count-1)`.  What's failing?

Comment: @TimRoberts This logic won't work if there is negative & positive number combination. for eg Min = -10 ,Max =10, Intervals count =6 :-(

Comment: @TimRoberts' approach *does* work with negative numbers for min and/or for max. And how can we possibly see the problem in a solution you don't show us?

Comment: It absolutely does work, for EVERY combination.  "(10-(-10))/5" is 4.  You'll get `(-10,-6,-2,2,6,10)`.